# Couture and canapé are just another Saturday night until you add a mask. [Why the singular 'canapé'?]

Tags: articles, countable-nouns, french, zero-article

In an American TV show called 'Gossip Girl', here's a narration by Gossip Girl herself ([YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H5TENF_kPpE?t=10)):

> Long ago, when European royals grew bored with palace balls they took a page from the peons, and added some pageantry. Couture and **canapé** are just another Saturday night until you add a mask. But preparing for a ball is an event in itself. Which is why queens invented handmaidens.

*Couture* is a non-count noun, so it can be used without any determiner, but why is the count noun *canapé* in the singular without any determiner? Should it be in the plural as follows?

> Couture and **canapés** are just another Saturday night until you add a mask.

Is this simply a mistake on the part of writer and/or narrator? Or is there any legitimate reason for this?

Comment: Surely this is a question about correct French pronunciation, the "s" being silent, unless you think that since it's for an English speaking audience it should have been voiced? Are you getting subtitles that I'm not? "Encana pay" is what it said here.

Comment: Since the sentence is about European royalty it would seem entirely proper to use French pronunciation.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. The subtitles on the video are auto generated and unreliable; the correct transcription is as shown in the OP.

Comment: @DJClayworth AFAIK, the English pronunciation canapé (as pronounced in the video) is nowhere close to its authentic French pronunciation.

Comment: What's the source of the transcription in your question?

Comment: Nowhere close indeed. Without your transcript, I would have recognized neither *couture* nor *canapé* by listening to the narration. Even knowing they are used (if they really are), I fail to understand what exactly this sentence means. In any case, In French *couture et canapé* to generically describe an activity and its location would likely use the singular for both.